# query data not show in mvc 4 View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created View model for combining two several classes to display several models in a single view. I have created linq query to display data in View. this is my Controller.

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {

        var sp_details = (from s in db.service_provider 
                          join p in db.pictures on s.SPID equals p.SPID 
                          join c in db.cities on s.City_ID equals c.City_ID 
                          //where s.SPID==id
                          select new ImageData()
                          { 
                             SPID = s.SPID,
                             Sp_name = s.Sp_name,
                             Sp_location = s.Sp_location,
                             Sp_description = s.Sp_description, 
                             Sp_rate = s.Sp_rate, 
                             service_type = s.service_type, 
                             Cityname= c.Cityname, 
                             pic = p.pic });

        if (sp_details == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(sp_details);
    }
```

This is Details View. I want to get one specific Profile to View.

```
@model IEnumerable<WEB1.ViewModel.ImageData>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
 }

<div class="span9">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <p class="name">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sp_name)</p>
                  <p class="cattype">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sp_location)</p>
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>Opening Hours</td>
                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cnt_wh)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sp_description)</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Rate</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sp_rate)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><p>@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Hotel")</p></td>
                </tr>
            </table>}
```

this is Index View. it passed id value after click on hyperlink.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="item1">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.pic,0,item.pic.Length)" width="100" />
            <p class="name">@Html.ActionLink(item.Sp_name, "Details", new { id = item.SPID },null)</p>
            <p class="cattype">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sp_location)</p>
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cityname)</p>
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sp_rate)</p>
        </div>

    }
```

I have removed commented line in query then I got all list items. But I want to get one specific value.I have added commented line and then I got Blank page with out error but no data.

Comment: Do you have a record in your table(s) which is matching the code in the where clause ?

Comment: yes.From Index view there is a hyper link to click.I will add it also to question

Comment: So are you saying that your linq query (with the where clause) is giving a result of 0 items even though you have data in your tables ? That does not sound rite ! Can you verify your join's are correct ?

Comment: my join 's are correct with out `where...` I have retrieved all the data in list

Comment: Then your where clause is wrong !

Comment: how it happen? can you suggest way to correct it?

Comment: Are you sure the id you want is being passed in?  You have a default of 0, not sure what you expect when that is used.

Comment: Hover over sp_details.  What variable type does the intellisense say it is (both with and without the comment).

Comment: Are you sure that SPID of `db.service_provider ` (which you want to see details) has realationed data on `db.pictures` and `db.cities`? If not, your query will allways return 0 results since there are inner joins.

Comment: add you where clause and change the following if (sp_details == null) to if (sp_details.Count() <= 0){...} , you will see that is going to the HttpNotFound();, now I think that the id that you are passing is 0 or another number how doesn't have any records on you db or doesn't have relationship between the other tables (inner), the reason that you're not seeing any error is because  sp_details  is not null and the foreach loop is not going to throw any error just is going to do nothing, and other thing in your view you have item.Cnt_wh but in your controller never is mapped

Comment: `sp_details` is never `null`.

Comment: @Balde ofcourse. Query has return data.but when I 'm trying to get one specific data in another view it is blank

Comment: @DanielGpeReyes  I have tried that also. again it returns blank page